# Automatically enable telnet services with batch

Tags: windows, batch

Even after installing telnet it will not work until you go services.msc and enable Telnet by changing the setting to automatic. Is there a way I can do this preferably with cmd or otherwise with powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. In the command prompt type.

`sc config tlntsvr start = auto`

You can save this as a `.bat` file and run it whenever required, no need of typing it every time in the command prompt.